@pushOnce for component supplemental files with Vite in Laravel Blade
I use the component design pattern to build my UI in Laravel (v10) Blade, sticking with single-file components as often as possible. Certain complex components are still easier when scripts, styles, and DOM live in their own files, however. How do I efficiently link these files?
Including <link> and <script src=""> elements in the Blade file is easy enough; but presents two problems: (1) Blade’s full-page reloads bypass Vite’s awesome HMR, and (2) a linked file can be loaded more than once.
Laravel solutions I’ve tried
@vite() solves the first problem neatly, but makes the second worse: the Vite client script is linked not just once per page, but every time Blade parses the @vite directive. (I know that’s more than necessary, because the HTML generated by passing an array, like @vite([ 'variables.scss', 'theme.scss' ]), links the Vite client script only once.)
Wrapping it in a @once directive doesn’t solve the problem either. The @once directive controls multiple renders of its own Blade component, but a @once in a parent component won’t prevent an identical @once in a child component.
Nor have the @stack() and @push() (and @pushOnce()) directives helped. Semantically, “push” appears to mean “defer to a section rendered later” (where “later” is defined by @stack). If the stack is defined before anything has been pushed to it (i.e, in the <head> of a page template component), it will be rendered empty. And the @push() calls need to be outside the main Blade content, effectively ruling out its use in nested components.
Then does the @yield directive, which creates a “vacuum” where @section contents are put, solve the issue? Again, no: it might have the right sequence, but it can only be effectively used once, and it appears to suffer from the same nesting issue that stacks have.
Code
/resources/views/public-layout.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @vite([
        'resources/css/variables.scss',
        'resources/css/theme.scss',
    ])
    @stack( 'css' )
</head>
<body>
    {{ $slot }}
</body>
</html>

/resources/views/search-results-page.blade.php
<x-public-layout>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <x-drawer ui-position="bottom" >
        <h4>Have some feedback?</h4>
    </x-drawer>
</x-public-layout>

/resources/views/components/drawer.blade.php
@props([ 'uiPosition' => 'top' ])
@pushOnce('css') @vite("resources/css/x-drawer.scss") @endPushOnce

<dialog class="x-drawer" data-position="{{ $uiPosition }}">
    {{ $slot }}
</dialog>

rendered HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module" src="http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://[::1]:5173/resources/css/variables.scss" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://[::1]:5173/resources/css/theme.scss" />
    <!-- missing link to x-drawer.scss file -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <dialog class="x-drawer" data-position="bottom">
        <h4>Have some feedback?</h4>
    </dialog>
</body>
</html>

